# Include ODBC Library in AWS Lambda Python Deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, odbc, aws-lambda, pypyodbc

I have created a Deployment Package for AWS Lambda, written in Python 2.7. In the Python script, I use pypyodbc to connect to an external data source, using a User DNS that I have configured on my local machine. When I attempt to deploy the package, I get the following error:

```
module initialization error: 'ODBC Library is not found. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?'
```

I created the package `project-dir` using pip into a virtual environment. The package is arranged as follows:

```
/project-dir
  __init__.py
  PythonFileIWantToUse.py
  pypyodbc.py
  pypyodbc.pyc
  /boto
  /pypyodbc-1.3.3.dist-info
  /other modules, etc.
```

I've tried adding

`#Point Lambda to Required OBDC Directory
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] + ':' + '/var/task/'`

to `MainPythonIWantToUse.py` above the lambda_handler function, and including odbc32.lib in the root directory, but I got the same error.

Any idea what I need to do? I configured a local ODBC in Windows, but I'm not sure what file(s) to put where for Lambda's Unix Environment to find them.

Edit: I've tried to include the elements of UnixODBC in the root directory as well, but this doesn't change the result.

Comment: Just wondering of you ever got this working...I'm also stuck.

Comment: I believe you need to use Linux ODBC drivers: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588262/tesseract-ocr-on-aws-lambda-via-virtualenv

Comment: Hey, you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682991/aws-lambda-function-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-python