# AWS Lambda function to connect to SQL Server with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been stuck trying to connect to an SQL Server using AWS Lambda functions for a long while now.

To do so i'm trying to use any library (tried with pyodbc, pypyodbc, etc), packaging everything into a zip file and uploading the code.

The code is pretty much the same for every library, but the errors are different.

The code:

```
import pypyodbc

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=1.1.1.1;'
                      'DATABASE=dbname;'
                      'UID=user;'
                      'PWD=pwd')

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Table")

    item_count = 0

    for row in cur:
        item_count += 1

    print(item_count)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return item_count
```

Common issues that i have covered: 
 - I'm adding to the zip the project contents, not the folder.
 - I'm also adding to the zip file the libraries needed for the code to run.

**If i try to use pyodbc**, the zip i'm uploading looks like this:

```
.idea (dir)
pyodbc (dir)
lambda_function.py
pyodbc.pyd
```

The error i get:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named pyodbc
```

After searching for quite a while about this, i couldn't find anything that helps. Only one comment that said that pyodbc needed to be instaled on a linux enviroment for the lambda function to work. But i don't have that Enviroment available, also i don't know if that will fix this.

**If i try to use pypyodbc**, the zip i'm uploading looks like this:

[image]

The error i get:

```
module initialization error: 'ODBC Library is not found. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?'
```

For this one i tried to install multiple python packages suggested by other stackoverflow posts (python-pyodb, unixodbc), but i failed every time.

Then there was one comment around saying "Make sure to put native ODBC libraries under the lib folder in your zip deployment package"

Maybe that is some help? I don't know how to get native ODBC libraries..

Oh and one last thing. Both libraries work if i run them from my local machine. I can get access to the target server. It fails if i do it from the lambda function.

Hopefully someone can help me and, apparently, the whole internet with this.

Comment: you can create an ec2-instance and create the virtual env and install all your dependencies and zip them. and try to use that zip file to install.

Comment: I will see if i can try that. That's the only approach left i have but i was trying to avoid it.. Thanks Usman.

Comment: @EmilianoRodriguez I'm having the same issue. Is Usman Azhar's comment really what you had to resort to or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I was in a project testing this functionality but we gave up trying to implement this method and moved to other things. If i remember correctly i was stuck trying to build the package to upload, but couldn't achieve that. My best attempt was to build the package on a linux machine. 

There's a new comment in this section from a few days ago, maybe you should check it out to see if it helps.

Answer (score 8):

- you need to know Lambda copy your function in local /var/task/
- create a instance using Lambda official AMI
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html
- start instance, login
- `yum install gcc gcc-c++`
- go in to /home/ec2-user
- Download the last unixodbc manager from:
  ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/
- `wget ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.5.tar.gz`
- `tar xvzf unixODBC-2.3.5.tar.gz`
- `cd unixODBC-2.3.5`
- configure it with the correct sysconfdir value

  `./configure  --sysconfdir=/var/task  --disable-gui --disable-drivers --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE  --prefix=/home`
- `make install`
- Go to /home dir and copy bin,include,lib,share directory on your computer where the Lambda project is (ex: C:\AWS\Lambda\sql_query)
- install on your EC2 instance the the Microsoft driver libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1 and then copy the driver file on your PC local directory (ex: C:\AWS\Lambda\sql_query\msodbcsql\msodbcsql\lib64 )
- Take a look
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/02/04/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/
- On your computer, in the same root directory create file odbcinst.ini

`[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/var/task/msodbcsql/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1
UsageCount=1`

- On your computer, in the same root directory create file odbc.ini

  `[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
  Driver      = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
  Description = My ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
  Trace       = No`
- on your python program use pyodbc:

  `import pyodbc
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
      server = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
      cursor = cnxn.cursor()
      ...other things....`
- and now play the game !

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Max, i'm not working on this anymore but there sure will be people finding this of help.

Comment: @maxmonterumisi, do you have the code in some repo? I was follow the instructions but didn't work. Could you share the structure? Thanks

Comment: Hey, you can follow this instructions https://gist.github.com/carlochess/658a98589709f46dbb3d20502e48556b

Comment: Hey Max. I tried with most of it but still stuck. Can you help me in this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365543/unable-to-get-a-sql-server-driver-in-aws-lambda-to-connect-to-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python 3.9 solution that uses [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

See [this Github gist comment](https://gist.github.com/diriver63/b72a954fa0da4851d89e5086aa13c6e8?permalink_comment_id=4199559#gistcomment-4199559).

Based on:

- Python 3.9
- AWS's [base images for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html)
- unixODBC-2.3.11

1. Create this `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   # Dockerfile

   FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9
   ENTRYPOINT []

   WORKDIR /root

   # Get development tools to enable compiling
   RUN yum -y update
   RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"

   # Get unixODBC and install it
   RUN yum -y install tar gzip
   RUN curl ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz -O
   RUN tar xvzf unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz
   WORKDIR /root/unixODBC-2.3.11
   RUN ./configure --sysconfdir=/opt/python --disable-gui --disable-drivers --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE --prefix=/root/unixODBC-install
   RUN make install
   RUN mv /root/unixODBC-install/bin /opt/bin
   RUN mv /root/unixODBC-install/lib /opt/lib
   WORKDIR /root

   # Install msodbcsql
   RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
   RUN yum -y install e2fsprogs openssl
   RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum -y install msodbcsql mssql-tools --disablerepo=amzn*
   RUN rm -r /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql

   # Install pyodbc
   # Need "unixODBC-devel" to avoid "src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory" during pip install
   RUN yum -y install unixODBC-devel
   RUN export CFLAGS="-I/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/include"
   RUN export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib"
   RUN pip install pyodbc==4.0.32 adodbapi==2.6.2.0 pyDes==2.0.1 --upgrade --target /opt/python

   # Add a requirements.txt file and enable this section to install other (non sql server) data-load requirements
   # COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
   # RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt --target /opt/python

   # Create odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini
   RUN echo $'[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]\nDriver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\nDescription = My ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\nTrace = No' > /opt/python/odbc.ini
   RUN so_file=$(ls /opt/microsoft/**/lib64/libmsodbcsql-*.so.* | grep msodbcsql17) && echo $'[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]\nDescription = Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\nDriver = '"$so_file"$'\nUsageCount = 1' > /opt/python/odbcinst.ini

   # Generate the zipped file that can be uploaded as a Lambda Layer
   WORKDIR /opt
   RUN zip -r /layer.zip .
   ```
2. Build the Dockerfile and extract the resulting zip file:

   ```bash
   # Build the image (this will take a while...)
   $ docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t mssql-lambda .
   # Copy the zipped file to /tmp/pyodbc.zip on your computer
   $ docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm --volume /tmp:/tmp mssql-lambda cp /layer.zip /tmp/
   ```
3. Upload `/tmp/layer.zip` [from your computer to AWS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/layers) as a Lambda Layer.
4. Create and run a Python 3.9 Lambda to test things out:
   (Make sure you configure it to use the Layer you created in the previous step)

   ```py
   import pyodbc

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
       server = 'XXX'
       port = '1433'
       database =  'XXX'
       username = 'XXX'
       password = 'XXX' # ideally put this in a SecretsManager secret instead of directly in the code
       connection = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server},{port};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       query = """
           select @@version
       """

       cursor.execute(query)

       for row in cursor.fetchall():
           print(row[0])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is uploading the layer without the appropriate folder structure specified in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path)

Answer (score 0):

1. Downloaded the pyodbc-layer from the following repo
   https://github.com/kuharan/Lambda-Layers/blob/master/3.7/lambda_function.py
2. Created a new layer in aws lambda for assisting in the pyodbc directory.
3. Once the lambda has been deployed
4. Attached this new created layer to the function and than executed it.

TADA problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my github repo with automated builds of the the ODBC 18 drivers for Python 3.11 and 3.12.
Prebuilt packages and Dockerfile for x86_64 and ARM64

https://github.com/davidcomerford/pyodbc-mssql-lambda-layer

I like to pull the latest version of unixodbc from Amazons repo. This feels a lot safer than everyone else's fixed versions, security, bugfixes, etc.

Here's the x86_64 Dockerfile for example...

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.12
ENTRYPOINT []

# Install general tools
RUN dnf install -y "dnf-command(download)"
RUN dnf install -y tar
RUN dnf group install -y "Development Tools"

# Install unixODBC
WORKDIR /root
RUN dnf download --source unixODBC
RUN rpm -ivh unixODBC*.src.rpm
WORKDIR /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES
RUN mkdir /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/unixODBC
RUN tar -xvf unixODBC*.tar.gz -C unixODBC --strip-components=1
WORKDIR /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/unixODBC
RUN ./configure --sysconfdir=/opt/python --disable-gui --disable-drivers --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE --prefix=/root/unixODBC-install
RUN make install
RUN mv /root/unixODBC-install/bin /opt/bin
RUN mv /root/unixODBC-install/lib /opt/lib

# Install msodbcsql
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/9/prod.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y dnf install -y msodbcsql18

# Install pyodbc
RUN dnf -y install unixODBC-devel
RUN export CFLAGS="-I/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/include"
RUN export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib"
RUN pip3 install pyodbc --upgrade --target /opt/python

# Create odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini
RUN echo $'[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]\nDriver = ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server\nDescription = My ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server\nTrace = No' > /opt/python/odbc.ini
RUN so_file=$(ls /opt/microsoft/**/lib64/libmsodbcsql-*.so.* | grep msodbcsql18) && echo $'[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]\nDescription = Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server\nDriver = '"$so_file"$'\nUsageCount = 1' > /opt/python/odbcinst.ini

# Generate the zipped file that can be uploaded as a Lambda Layer
WORKDIR /opt
RUN zip -r /layer.zip .
```