# Connect to SQL Server using Lambda

Tags: sql-server, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc through a Lambda function.
I have downloaded and put the driver file in an s3 bucket.

This is the code -

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    r"DRIVER={s3://file_name/libodbc.so.2};"
    r"SERVER=*;"
    r"DATABASE=*;"
    r"UID=*;"
    r"PWD=*")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I am getting the following error -

> errorMessage": "('01000', \"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 's3://file_name/libodbc.so.2' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)\")"

Comment: Package the ODBC driver with your Lambda.  You can't reference it that way in Lambda.  You could initially copy from S3 into Lambda but it's easier to package it all up.  See the [Python Lambda docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) for more information.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682991/aws-lambda-function-to-connect-to-sql-server-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Install PYMSQL and use this to connect SQL server database using below method:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```