# Why i can not use tesseract in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, tesseract

I created a virtualenv (python3.5) then i install tesseract .
but i can't use it in virtualenv and throw a error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/spider/demo2.py", line 5, in 
>       vcode = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
>     File "/Users/abc/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
>       config=config)
>     File "/Users/abc/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
>       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

but in  real environment  i can get right result so what happended? what can i do ?

Comment: Did you install it on virtualenv?

Comment: how to install tesseract on virtualenv? i can execute tesseract on  virtualenv

Comment: Any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588262/tesseract-ocr-on-aws-lambda-via-virtualenv?

Comment: i use command venv to create a virtualenv ,not a virtual machine,i think virtualenv only separate interpreter and its libraries .why i need install a new one @Giordano

Comment: I don't understand if you installed tesseract in virtualenv or only in "real env"